# What's the intuition behind the Wigner function of a Fock state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, optics, quantum-optics

The Wigner function for a Fock state with $n>1$ has "ripples" leading away from the center. For example, the $n=4$ Fock state looks like this:
[image]

The marginals of this distribution give the electric field at different phases.

Here's my confusion:

I'm confused that the probability distribution for the electric field of a Fock state has a range of possible values. If, say, the light were incident on an electron transition separated by $E=h\nu$ with $\nu$ the frequency of the photon, I would think that the electron is excited with probability 1. But if the electric field can be measured to be 0, it seems that some of the time the electron will not be excited.

If the electric field can take on multiple values, it seems that it can impart different amounts of work on a charged particle. But that goes against my intuition since the Fock state has definite energy, and therefore I would think it imparts a definite amount of work on a charged particle.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Note that $\langle n|\hat{E}|n\rangle=0$. So this distribution does not play a role here.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking about the behavior of the S H oscillator stationary state
$$
f_4(x,p)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int\!\!dy ~e^{typ} \psi_4^*(x-\hbar y/2) \psi_4(x+\hbar y/2),
$$
a fancy convolution of 4th [Hermite functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials#Hermite_functions), (proportional to Hermite polynomials enveloped by a Gaussian); which, of course, is proportional to the 4th [Laguerre polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laguerre_polynomials#The_first_few_polynomials) of an axially symmetric argument, $L_4\left ( 2 \frac{x^2+p^2}{\hbar}\right )$ ; which, therefore, has 4 nodes: four rings of zeros. It oscillates and goes negative in two rings of minimum troughs. Thus, it cannot be a probability density, but is, instead, a quasi-probability density.

As you surmised (?) the rescaled (Weyl-symbol) hamiltonian $H=(x^2+p^2)/2$ leads to no energy variance in this stationary state,
$$
0=\langle H\star H\rangle - \langle H \rangle^2= \langle H^2 \rangle -\langle H \rangle^2 -\hbar^2/4,$$
predictably.

By partial contrast, the marginal projection is positive semi-definite, necessarily; but oscillatory, yet again,
$$
\int\!\! dp ~ f_4(x,p) = |\psi_4(x) |^2, 
$$
with 4 nodes, coming from the zeros of the Hermite functions and  hence Hermite polynomials. It is a bona-fide probability density.

Not clear what further intuition you are after.

- You must, however, specify why this is counterintuitive to you; any and all discussion of electric fields is quite garbled in your question. Fields consist of an infinity of quantum oscillators, not just one, whose Wigner function puzzles you...

Comment: Thank you for the reply @CosmasZachos! I've added clarity about my confusion to the question. To summarize: I think I'm conflating uncertainty in the electric field with uncertainty in the work that can be applied by the field to a charged particle the field interacts with. This is confusing to me, since the Fock state has definite energy.

Comment: I see, but I have no clue what Wigner functions (strictly in phase-space) have to do with an of this... Why don't you stick to the more familiar Hilbert space, instead?

Comment: I'm just using the Wigner function here as a visual aid to help understand what the electric field probability distribution looks like.

Comment: You might, but the reader has no clue of what you are up to, and you need to specify it in your question more explicitly; on the face of it, it appears downright unsound, but you might have a valid point, which you have failed to make...